# Could someone explain this C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Hi, I recently came across this syntax in a C++ program. This is not passing parameters to a base class constructor as I know what that looks like and how to code it. This looks like some sort of variable initialization for the class... Here is the code:

```
class Particle
{
private:
  bool movable;
  float mass;
  Vec3 pos;
  Vec3 old_pos; 
  Vec3 acceleration;
  Vec3 accumulated_normal;
public:
  Particle(Vec3 pos)
  : pos(pos),
    old_pos(pos),
    acceleration(Vec3(0,0,0)),
    mass(1),
    movable(true),
    accumulated_normal(Vec3(0,0,0))
  {}

  Particle() {}

  // More unrelated code
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the syntax for member initialization, as you surmised. Contrast this:

```
class C
{
private:
  int i;
public:
  C(int i_) : i(i_) {} // initialization
};
```

with:

```
class C
{
private:
  int i;
public:
  C(int i_) { i = i_; } // assignment
};
```

It's generally better to initialize members rather than assigning to them in the constructor body, and there are some cases where it's essential (one example would be references).

Answer (score 6):

Initialisation lists can be used to initialise member variables as well as parents. This is the correct way of writing a constructor - initialisation like this is more efficient than doing assignment in the constructor body, and is likely semantically more correct.

Comment: +1 It should also be noted that member variables have to be initialised in the order they are declared.

Comment: @Helper But not in the initialisation list, where order is not significant.

Comment: Ah, sry, ofc you are correct. Another reason why to use them :-).

Comment: @Helper Method: Slightly unclear actually. They *are* initialized in the order they're declared, regardless of the order in which you write them in the initialization list. Thus you probably *should* write them in the order in which they're declared, for clarity.

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: +1. Most compiler actually issue a warning when you don't.

Comment: @Stuart This is true, and gcc actually produces an irritating warning if you don't.

Comment: @ereOn: It's not always turned on by default :) But most compilers can be made to issue such a warning.

Comment: To follow on from that, I just tested, and VC++ with warning level 3 (the default) doesn't output such a warning.